# Storybook: Static build assets are not loading

Tags: reactjs, storybook, radium

I am building storybook. When trying to load the resulting files, I get this error.

```
manager.43f5b3475a944261b3fa.bundle.js:formatted:19449 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined
at resolveStyles (manager.43f5b3475a944261b3fa.bundle.js:formatted:19449)
at RadiumEnhancer.render (manager.43f5b3475a944261b3fa.bundle.js:formatted:19191)
at callMethod (manager.43f5b3475a944261b3fa.bundle.js:formatted:409)
at RadiumEnhancer.render (manager.43f5b3475a944261b3fa.bundle.js:formatted:414)
at renderComponent (manager.43f5b3475a944261b3fa.bundle.js:formatted:821)
at setComponentProps (manager.43f5b3475a944261b3fa.bundle.js:formatted:805)
at buildComponentFromVNode (manager.43f5b3475a944261b3fa.bundle.js:formatted:686)
at idiff (manager.43f5b3475a944261b3fa.bundle.js:formatted:691)
at innerDiffNode (manager.43f5b3475a944261b3fa.bundle.js:formatted:743)
at idiff (manager.43f5b3475a944261b3fa.bundle.js:formatted:753)
```

Comment: could u show us the code.. Also seems you are using radium decorator for inline style.

Comment: I submitted the issue with all the code. I am not using radium, at least not intending to use it. I am not sure why that code is being invoked. https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/issues/3113